# How do I get a separate key and value from the resulting json?

Tags: php

I send data to **function.php**

```
method: 'POST',
JSON.stringify( { username1: 'example1', username2: 'example2' } ),
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
},
```

How do i analyze this data and return each key and value separately? 
***username1*** or ***example1*** or ***username2*** or ***example2***

I tried this

```
$data = json_encode($_POST);
echo $data;
```

But this code returns a strange object, where all data is in the key and the value is empty
**{{"username1":"example1","username2":"example2"}: ""}**

This also doesn't work

```php
    $data["username1"]; // return only {
    $data->username1; // return empty
```

I don't know if this will help

```
var_dump($_POST);
array(1) {
  ["{"username1":"example1","username2":"example2"}"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

and

```
var_dump(json_encode($_POST));
string(62) "{"{\"username1\":\"example1\",\"username2\":\"example2\"}":""}"
```

Comment: Just to clarify for my sake, are you trying to get the value of a json object?

Comment: I would say you're doing json_encode on json encoded POST. Perhaps you're looking for json_decode function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what your asking for is calling on values within an object being returned from json I think this may help (providing i understand your answer)

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data); // This will parse the json data thats being returned 
var username = obj[0].username1;
console.log(username);
```

That should log in the console the value of the JSON object you created.